# Getting user's hometown info

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get my own hometown info from my profile, but it always returns null. However, when I got the graph API (https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token=) for my account, it returns there.

Here's my code:

```
    SocialMatchUser model = new SocialMatchUser();
        var authClient = new FacebookOAuthClient(FacebookApplication.Current)
        {            
            AppId = appId,
            AppSecret = appSecret,
            RedirectUri = new Uri(redirectUrl)
        };

        dynamic token = authClient.ExchangeCodeForAccessToken(Request.QueryString["code"]);
        var client = new FacebookClient(token.access_token);            
        dynamic me = client.Get("me");

        model.ID = Convert.ToInt64(me.id);
        model.FullName = me.name;
        model.FirstName = me.first_name;
        model.LastName = me.last_name;
        model.Link = me.link;
        model.UserName = me.username;
        model.Gender = me.gender;
        model.Locale = me.locale;
        model.Birthday = me.birthday;

        if (me.hometown!= null)
        {
            model.HometownId = Convert.ToInt64(me.hometown.id);
            model.Hometown = me.hometown.name;
        }

        return View(model);
```

Am I missing something in my request or original auth call to allow access to this extra user info?

Thanks!
-Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to request extended permissions to read out the hometown.

You can find details here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I was looking for!